# select specific decendants using Jquery

Tags: jquery

In [JQuery's Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) the `"parent > child"` selector selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent". "Direct child" is just the element one level down. For example, I have this code:

```
    ...
    <table class="advanceSearch">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <ul class="form">
            <li>
              <label>Document Type:</label>
              <input type="text" id="cmbDocumentType" name="paramtitle" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Title:</label>
              <input type="text" id="paramtitle" name="paramtitle" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Notes:</label>
              <input type="text" id="paramNotes" name="paramNotes" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Revision Number:</label>
              <input type="text" id="paramRevisionNumber" name="paramRevisionNumber" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Draft Number:</label>
              <input type="text" id="paramDraftNumber" name="paramDraftNumber" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Version Number:</label>
              <input type="text" id="paramVersionNumber" name="paramVersionNumber" />
            ...
```

I want to select the `input` elements with ids starting with "param", and so I used the `find()` instead of the `parent > child` selector:

```
      $("table.advanceSearch").find("ul.form").find('input[id^="param"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

This works well but I find it redundant having two `find()` selectors. Is there any way to have the shorthand for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need `.find()` at all; you can use two descendant selectors instead.

```
$('table.advanceSearch ul.form input[id^="param"]')
```

Remember: `x > y` (the child selector) is more-or-less interchangeable with `$('x').children('y')`, and `$('x y')` is more-or-less interchangeable with `$('x').find('y')`.

Comment: I used `$('table.advanceSearch input[id^="param"]');` after reading [this](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) but your answer is also correct! Thanks anyway. :))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('table.advanceSearch ul.form input[id^="param"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

OR

```
$('table.advanceSearch ul.form').find('input[id^="param"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

OR

```
$('table.advanceSearch ul.form li').children('input[id^="param"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: +1 for a correct answer, but Mr. Matt got it first, but thanks too :)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector can be much longer:

```
$(".advanceSearch input[id^='param']").prop("disabled", true);
```

This will do the same, without the verbosity.